# Adding a filter in hubspot

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-cms

I want to add a filter in my contacts, https://knowledge.hubspot.com/es/contacts/create-saved-filters:

[image]

But I don't see this option :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a field named "more filter" available at the end. this one open a model with the list of your properties for adding filters to the contact based on the property data you entered
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be easily solved, just follow the following few steps:

1. Go to the *Contacts* tab, click the *More Filters*  tab, and open the right sidebar:

   [image]
2. Then, filter by the *Contact properties* search box to find the wanted properties:

   [image]
3. And, finally, check the *is known* radio button and press the *Apply filter* button.

   [image]